# Passing params from within <g:each> to action specified in createLink within a javascript function, called on clicking <a:> link

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a template containing a g:each that renders a set of search results in tabular format as follows:

```
<g:if test="${company}">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small"><g:message code="Company Name"/></th>
        <th class="medium"><g:message code="TDCID"/></th>
        <th class="tiny"><g:message code="STREET"/></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <g:each in="${company}" status="idx" var="PNo">

       <tr>
         <td>
         <a: href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:asd();" params="[tdc:PNo.tdcId,companyid:PNo.companyId,companytype:PNo.companyType]">//params: passing not working now.Have to pass the tdcId,companyId,companyType of clicked result
                ${PNo.officialName}
         </a:>
         </td>
         <td>
                          ${PNo.tdcId}

         </td>
         <td>

              ${PNo.street}

         </td>
       </tr>

    </g:each>
   </tbody>
  </table>     
  </g:if>
```

I need to pass tdcId,companyId,companyType contained in company object that is clicked by user to the following JavaScript function:

```
function asd(){
 window.open("${g.createLink(controller: 'Customer', action:   'showcontacts',params:'[tdc:company.tdcId,companyid:company.companyId,companytype:company.companyType]')}",'', 'width=200,height=100');
 }
```

Here from asd() I need to pass the params to action:'showcontacts' through createLink tag. What is the right way to do this?

This is the calling gsp: _customers.gsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function asd(tdcId, companyId, companyType) {
 alert(tdcId);
   var link = "${g.createLink(controller: 'Customer', action: 'showcontacts')}?tdc=" + tdcId +  "&companyid=" + companyId + "&companytype=" + companyType;
   window.open(link, '', 'width=200,height=100');
}

</script>

<div class="form-edit">
    <div class="heading">
        <strong>
            <g:message code="Firm Profile"/>
        </strong>
    </div>

    <div id="hai" class="form-hold">
        <g:form name="company-edit-form" action="save">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-columns">


                    <div class="column">
                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Company Name"/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Company</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Company"  id="Company"  />
                        </g:applyLayout>
                         <g:applyLayout name="form/checkbox">
                             <content tag="label"><g:message code="Starts with"/</content>
                             <content tag="label.for">Starts with</content>
                             <g:checkBox class="cb checkbox" name="StartsWith" />
                        </g:applyLayout>
                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Street"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Street</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Street" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                         <g:applyLayout name="form/checkbox">
                             <content tag="label"><g:message code="Starts with"/</content>
                             <content tag="label.for">Starts With</content>
                             <g:checkBox class="cb checkbox" name="StreetStartsWith"/>
                        </g:applyLayout>
                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Zip code"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Zip</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="ZipCode"/>
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Fagrubrik"/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Fagrubrik</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Fagrubrik" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="House no."/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">HouseNo</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="HouseNo" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Tel./Fax."/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Telephone</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Telephone" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Company No."/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">CompanyNo</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="CompanyNo" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="City"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">City</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="City" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="TDC ID"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">TdcId</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="TdcId" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Industry Designation"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Industry Designation</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="IndustryDesignation" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Decision Maker"/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">DecisionMaker</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="DecisionMaker" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Email"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Email</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Email" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="WWW"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">WWW</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="WWW"/>
                             </g:applyLayout>
                    </div>


                </div>


                <div>
                    <br/>&nbsp;
                </div>

                <div id="button" class="buttons">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <g:submitButton class="buttons" id="button" name="Search"
    value="Search" action="search"/>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

        </g:form>
           <div class="table-box">
           <g:if test="${company}"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small"><g:message code="Company Name"/></th>
        <th class="medium"><g:message code="TDCID"/></th>
        <th class="tiny"><g:message code="STREET"/></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${company}" status="idx" var="PNo">

       <tr>
         <td>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)"
  onClick="javascript:asd('${PNo.tdcId}','${PNo.companyId}', 
  '${PNo.companyType}');">${PNo.officialName}</a>


         </td>
         <td>
         <g:remoteLink action="show" id="${PNo}" before="register(this);" 
                       onSuccess="render(data, next);" params="[template:'show']">
             ${PNo.tdcId}
         </g:remoteLink>
         </td>
         <td>

              ${PNo.street}

         </td>
       </tr>

    </g:each>
   </tbody>
   </table>     
  </g:if>
  </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
```

This is the called one for test purposes.named _showcontacts.gsp:

```
 <body>

<div id="dialog" title="Contacts">
 hai
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your a tag like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:asd('${PNo.tdcId}', '${PNo.companyId}', '${PNo.companyType}');">${PNo.officialName}</a>
```

And Script like this:

```
<script>
function asd(tdcId, companyId, companyType) {
   var link = "${g.createLink(controller: 'test', action: 'test')}?tdc=" + tdcId + "&companyid=" + companyId + "&companytype=" + companyType;
   window.open(link, '', 'width=200,height=100');
}
</script>
```

Enjoy..

Comment: I tried this but not working:(When passed without parameters the window is opening.But with parameters not...